# Security software hates my sockets

Tags: c, security, sockets, winsock

I'm writing a program that I want to distribute to other people, but it uses sockets and most security software treats it as malware. How do I make this program work without telling people to lower their firewalls and exempt the program from scans? Could there be something I'm doing wrong with my sockets, or is this an issue with my program not having a digital certificate?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
int client(char *ip,int port,SOCKET *sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    *sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    connect(*sock,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    return 2;
}
void ssend(char *buffer,int len,SOCKET sock)
{
    int sent;
    int *tmp;
    char head[4];
    sent=0;
    tmp=(int*)&head;
    *tmp=htonl(len);
    while(sent<4)
    {
        sent+=send(sock,head,4-sent,0);
    }
    sent=0;
    while(sent<len)
    {
        sent+=send(sock,buffer,len-sent,0);
    }
}
void srecv(char *buffer,int *len,SOCKET sock)
{
    char head[4];
    recv(sock,head,4,MSG_WAITALL);
    *len=ntohl(*((int*)head));
    recv(sock,buffer,*len,MSG_WAITALL);
}
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    WSADATA dat;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2),&dat);
    SOCKET sock;
    char ip[256];
    char msg[1024];
    int port;
    scanf("%s",ip);
    scanf("%d",&port);
    printf("%d\n",client(ip,port,&sock));
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",msg);
        ssend(msg,strlen(msg),sock);
    }
}
```

Not pretty code, I know! I'm just trying to get a foothold on sockets with C.

Comment: Hard to say without being able to see what you are doing.

Comment: Oh sure, I'll add in my code.

Comment: That code is using POSIX sockets, but most Linux distributions don't have "security software" that flags executables as malware... On what OS is this program supposed to run?

Comment: @Borealid Looks like Windows, judging by the use of the `WSA` functions.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin : You are correct. Winsock2 is getting included which are windows sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do. It is impossible for firewall software to distinguish between malware which is "phoning home" or launching an attack on other machines and a legitimate program. Users have to give an explicit exception for this.

Well, there is one thing you can do: make your program work over a widely used port, like HTTP port 80, or the SSL counterpart 443.

Not even sure that will help, if the rule is based on the identity of the program, not only the port. There is a very good reason to restrict which applications can make HTTP connections over port 80. Port 80 is often used by malware for phoning home and downloading malicious crud.

Comment: What about programs like Minecraft or all those other games? And security software has never mangled up Python for using sockets. Is this because the Python and Java interpreters have digital certificates or something?

Comment: That was a little un-clear. I just seems like professionally developed programs somehow manage not to be constantly deleted by my security software, unlike programs I write.

Comment: Ah, what may be happening there is that the installer for the software adds the program to the list of authorized applications in the registry. I think `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\AuthorizedApplications\List`.